# Send multiple pieces of data through .ajax() for processing in PHP script

Tags: jquery, ajax, timer

I'm trying to send two separate groups of information through .ajax() to a PHP script for processing and running into problems.

In this scenario, the user enters a page and 1) a timer starts counting seconds and 2) the user has to fill out a series of inputs for a form. I'd like to send both groups of information (the current timer count and all the user inputs) to a PHP script when the user clicks a submit button.

I've can successfully send either one group of info OR the other but can't figure out a way to send both groups of data simultaneously through .ajax() at the same time.

Here is the jQuery I've got now, which attempts to send both pieces of data but fails:

```
 $(document).ready(function(){
    var count = 0;
    setInterval(function(){
        count++;
        $('#timer').html(count + ' secs.');
    },1000);

// displays user structureand suggested answers on structure page
$('#process_structure').click(function () {
    var text = $.ajax ({
        type: "POST",
        url: "structure_process.php",
        data: $('#inputs_structure').serialize(), data: {count: count},
        dataType: "json",
        async: false,
    }).responseText;
    $('#test_ajax').html(text); 
})
});
```

Any pointers would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: the timer could be set in the server side so the user can't manipulate it. You can use a session variable for that. the frontend timer can simply be a dummy

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming `structure_process.php` accepts both pieces of data together, you can use [`serializeArray()`](http://api.jquery.com/serializeArray/) instead of `serialize()`, append your extra piece of data, and then use [`jQuery.param()`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.param/) to convert the array to a string that `jQuery.ajax()` will accept.

```
$('#process_structure').click(function () {
    var postData = $('#inputs_structure').serializeArray();
    postData.push({name: 'count', value: count});
    var text = $.ajax ({
        type: "POST",
        url: "structure_process.php",
        data: $.param(postData),
        dataType: "json",
        async: false,
    }).responseText;
    $('#test_ajax').html(text);
});
```

Comment: Interesting. And I should be able to pull the count data out in the structure_process.php by using $_POST['count']? I might be missing something but I just tried your code and accessing the count through $_POST and couldn't get it

Comment: Yes, this would (should) add an additional value named `count` to the POST data.

Comment: Hmm. what you're saying makes sense to me but I can't get it to work. I get an "undefined index: count" error when try to post. Any ideas why?

Comment: You can do `console.log` or something equivalent on `postData` after the `push()` call if you want to check to see if the array is set up correctly, but this should work fine. It's possible there was something lost in translation between here and your code; you could post what you've tried that didn't work.

Comment: Thanks John! This worked perfectly. I was having trouble earlier because when I was working on this page I included an earlier version of the same AJAX call in the <head> and forgot about it. So all the new edits to my main js src were getting overridden and not used. Frustrating! But I appreciate the help and glad it's resolved.